# LaTeX book to bookdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I am new to R Markdown and bookdown.
What would be the easiest way to take a book written in LaTeX and make it in bookdown.

Here is an example of book https://www.overleaf.com/read/hjpgqbncvrwz

Thank you

Comment: Hi, did you already try to do some stuff with bookdown or are you a beginner with markdown / bookdown? If you've never used that, I strongly recommend the online books on [R Markdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/) and on [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/) to you. I've never made big documents with r markdown or bookdown, but I guess turning your project won't be too difficult since both support LaTeX expressions and you can use [child documents](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html) to separate your books in chapters.

Comment: Thanks @bretauv. I like your optimism "I guess turning your project won't be too difficult" but I am not convinced.

Comment: For my own purposes I've written an R function that converts a `knitr` `.Rnw` `LaTeX` file to an `.Rmd` file, requiring a bit of hand editing at the end.  The main work of the conversion script is automatic correct indenting for `itemize` and `enumerate` environments.